# On overleaf.com, Is there a way to switch the window showing the pdf_document from column_right to column_left?

Tags: overleaf

In Overleaf, Is there a way to switch the window showing the pdf_document from column_right to column_left?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Overleaf-specific questions are best addressed Overleaf's own helpdesk. I hear their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic.