# Is there a way to move the PDF preview window to the left side and the source code window to the right side?

Tags: overleaf

I've been looking at the Overleaf settings but I didn't find this option. If it's not possible, do you know any browser extension that can achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! A previous duplicate of this question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575074/218142) was closed. However, switching views isn't currently possible. You may want to contact Overleaf's support (very responsive crew!) to request this as a feature in a future release.

Comment: Oh my bad. Thanks for the answer, I'll do that.